# Localization/Language preferences doesn't change widget's language in android

Tags: android, localization, widget

In my application i let users to change language of application.I do this like this:

```
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);

        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];



        //get sharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        //get default local for first initialization
        String defaultLanguage = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        //check language preference everytime onCreate of all activities, if there is no choise set default language
        Locale newLocaleLanguage = new Locale(sharedPreferences.getString("newLanguagePref",defaultLanguage));
        //finally setdefault language/locale according to newLocaleLanguage.
        Locale.setDefault(newLocaleLanguage);
        configuration.locale = newLocaleLanguage;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        Log.i("DefaultLanguage", defaultLanguage);
        Log.i("PrefferedLanguage",sharedPreferences.getString("newLanguagePref",defaultLanguage));

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


        }
```

i could change the preffered local in all activities with this code.But localization doesn't work for widgets.Widgets always appear in local language of phone.

As you see, on LOG lines i check default language and preffered language and everthing is fine. They change according to language choise onUpdate method of widget.

In my opinion, widget can't see custom localization pref because it works on homescreen and it sees localization pref of phone.Is that right?

So,is that impossible to change language of widget?How can i handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But localization doesn't work for widgets.Widgets always appear in local language of phone.

You are calling `updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);` before you are changing the locale. Hence, any strings you get via `getString()` inside `updateAppWidget()` will be using the default device locale.

Move your `updateAppWidget()` call after the code that changes your process' locale. If that does not help, please post the code to `updateAppWidget()`, as perhaps there is an issue in how you are setting up your `RemoteViews`.

Comment: changing the place of updateAppWidget(..)  doesn't change anything.

I found my mistake.Previously, i didn't set all strings programmatically.I set strings that only need to be changed according to database.I thought that all strings will be changed on Local change like how they are changed in activities.After you asked about RemoteViews i tried to set all of strings programmatically and now all works.Thanks!

Comment: @eren130: "changing the place of updateAppWidget(..) doesn't change anything" -- perhaps not in your testing. However, bear in mind that your process will not run forever. If you are using any sort of automated updates to the app widget (e.g., `updatePeriodMillis`), and one of those has to start a fresh process for your app, you need to adjust your locale before attempting to populate the app widget. That being said, you are certainly correct that you need to update everything when setting up the `RemoteViews`. Glad to hear it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:supportsRtl="false"`